# How to configure Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers?

Tags: eclipse

I tried to write a C++ code on the latest release of eclipse for c/c++ developers but the editor space is disabled. I've Installed the latest versions of Java as well as GCC compiler 12.2.0_64 bit. I've a windows 64 bit OS.

I tried to create a new c++ project but as mentioned the editor plane is disabled.

Comment: You need to create a C++ class in the project and then you can edit that.